# Does return ends function if ifelse is used?

Tags: php, function, if-statement, scope, return

I am returning something inside if else statement. Does it ends whole function or only ifelse scope?

```
function user () {
    if (//first) {
        return TRUE;
    }
    //somecode

    if (//second) {
        return FALSE;
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

In above code if my first condition is true, does it end whole function or only first ifelse scope?

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself?

Comment: From the [PHP Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.return.php): `If called from within a function, the return statement immediately ends execution of the current function, and returns its argument as the value of the function call.`.... it really is useful reading the PHP Docs before asking on StackOverflow, saves both you and us time

Comment: After your comment I will try these kind of stupid issues by myself. Thank You! :) BTW I tried this but I was confused more.

Comment: @MarkBaker I always read PHP Docs in first place. But I just cant get rid of this confusion.

Comment: I suggest u to read return and continue and break and exit and die these r basics

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`return` ends whole function. **Always**.

So, if you first condition is `true`, no other actions in `user` function are executed and function just returns `true`.